# Angular 4.3 - Initiating Router in constructor of service crashes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

This issue is boggling my mind. I'm sure I am missing something very simple.

Here is my home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth/auth.service'
import { TestAuthService } from './../../services/auth/testauth.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [AuthService, TestAuthService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: TestAuthService) 
  { 
    //  authService.login();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginClick() {
    this.authService.login();
  }

}
```

Everything displays perfectly until I added TestAuthService to my component. Right now the main AuthService is not being used. Removing the import or not doesn't do anything.

Here is testauth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

@Injectable()
export class TestAuthService {
    auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        clientID: 'clientIdKeyString',
        domain: 'legitemail.auth0.com',
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        audience: 'https://legitemail.auth0.com/userinfo',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/callback',      
        scope: 'openid'
      });

      constructor(**private router: Router**) {}

      public login(): void {
        this.auth0.authorize();
      }

}
```

This is using auth0 which I installed through npm using

```
npm install --save auth0-js
```

It is being referred to in my .angular-cli.json file. I know this code definitely works when the constructor is empty because I have a login button that correctly redirects me to auth0's authentication page and redirects back to my callback url. However, my whole screen crashes when I include the router in the constructor (I bolded the part that isn't working).

I'm not sure how adding the router to the constructor calls the whole page to fail to load. Again, the only thing I change to make it work is removing the bolded parameter Router in my constructor.

The error is:

```
ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:7 ERROR Error: No provider for Router!
```

Comment: It's a really really bad idea to post sensitive information, such as your Auth0 clientID. I have edited your post, but it needs to be approved. If you see this sooner, please remove that.

Comment: And the error is...

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru I have edited it out. Forgot to do that sorry.

Comment: @JBNizet I have included the error message. Forgot at first, I apologize.

Comment: OK. Now read it. You're trying to use the Router service. But there is no such service. Not until you have added the RouterModule (which provides this service) to your NgModule's imports. https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: yes as JP Nizet has mentioned there is no routermodule to provide the service

Comment: @JBNizet Ah thank you. This is what I get for following multiple guides at once. I missed crucial setup details. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

As comments from JB Nizet have stated, a RouterModule must be included in the main NgModule

app.module.ts

I added

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

and then in my imports

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  AppMaterialModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot([])
],
```